# Why doesn't Pattern.pattern() embed the flag(s)?

Tags: java, regex

I've been playing around with regexes recently and noticed this.

```
Pattern pNoEmbed = Pattern.compile("[ a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Pattern pEmbed = Pattern.compile("(?i)[ a-z]+");
```

Here's the output of the `pattern()` methods that is supposed to return the string of the pattern. And `toString()` seems to return the same thing.

Both have case-insensitivity, so **why no `(?i)` in the first one**?
And if I wanted it, how would I get it other than `"(?i)" + pattern`?

```
System.out.println(pNoEmbed.pattern()); // [ a-z]+
System.out.println(pEmbed.pattern()); // (?i)[ a-z]+
```

And for sanity, both match fine.

```
String s = "hello World";
System.out.println(pNoEmbed.matcher(s).matches()); // true
System.out.println(pEmbed.matcher(s).matches()); // true
```

(Tested with Java 8)

---

More clarity:

I would like to embed one regex in another

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[ a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(p1.pattern() + "\\s+");
```

A bad example, because I know I can do this

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(p1.pattern() + "\\s+", p1.flags());
```

but, basically, I would want `p2.pattern()` to be `"(?i)[ a-z]+\\s+"`

Comment: what does .matcher().toString() return ?

Comment: I don't understand why you assume it should return the flag as part of the regex. `pattern()` returns the actual expression. If you want to get the flag(s), you can call `flags()`.

Comment: @shmosel My use case was that I want to embed one pattern string into another pattern string. Calling `.pattern()` is going to lose those flags at the end of `.compile()`.

Comment: In that case, @cricket_007, what you propose to do is not quite correct.  You do not want the flags of the embedded pattern to leak out to the trailing part of the containing pattern, so you'll want to use the `"(?i:...)"` form to express the whole embedded pattern as a non-capturing group with the applicable flags applied.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I guess I'm not really clear how non-capturing groups apply to the pattern flags

Comment: @cricket_007, supposing that the pattern you want to embed is `"embed"`, compiled with flag `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, the pattern `"head_(?i)embed_tail"` (compiled with no flags) matches more strings than does `"head_(?i:embed)_tail"` (with no flags).  In particular, the former matches `"head_embed_TAIL"`, but the latter does not.

Comment: Note also that you have a potential problem if you try to embed a pattern that contains anchors (`"^foo"`) and does not use multiline mode.  Maybe you don't need to worry about that, but it's at least something to consider.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Okay, so to use the non-matching group, I would need to use the "beginning" flags instead of the bit masks, correct?

Comment: (off-topic comment but may be useful) We can apply flags to part of regex. We can do it via `foo(?:flags)bar(?-flags)baz` or via `foo(?flags:bar)baz`. Second syntax is safer because it only sets flags for specific non-capturing group, while in first case part `(?-flags)` explicitly turns off **all** specified `flags` starting from that place, including global flags like `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`. This can be observed with `Pattern.compile("a(?-i)b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)` for which `flags()` returns `0` instead of expected `2` (since we used `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`).

Comment: It is also worth noticing that result of `flags()` describe state of flags *at the end* of regex.

Comment: @Pshemo, your assertion about `flags()` seems at odds with its docs: "The match flags specified when this pattern was compiled".  To the best of my knowledge and ability to interpret, this means the second argument passed to `Pattern.compile(String, int)`, or 0 if the pattern was obtained via `Pattern.compile(String)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was also confused by that, which us is why I said "expected `2`". Anyway here is demo which shows this behavior for `Pattern.compile(String, int)`: https://ideone.com/7y7nJt

Comment: @cricket_007, if I understand you correctly, yes, *when you embed the pattern* you would want to use the regex syntax that expresses the embedded pattern, with flags, as a non-capturing group.  It would not be appropriate to apply the flags bitmask of the embedded group to the whole pattern in which it is embedded.

Comment: @Pshemo, confirmed.  Wow.  Seems like a bug to me, but the behavior goes back at least to Java 6.

Comment: @Pshemo What's wrong with that? `0` makes sense for `(?-i)` because you are "disabling" it

Comment: @cricket_007 It is not that it is *wrong*, but such behavior can be seen as unexpected because `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` gives us feeling (perhaps because of upper-case) that it is kind of constant/permanent flag, which should be applied to entire regex. But as shown in that example it is not I just wanted to point that out since IMO it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both have case-insensitivity, **so why no (?i) in the first one**?

Most directly, because [`Pattern.pattern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#pattern())

> Returns the regular expression from which this pattern was compiled.

I suppose that begs the question of why there is not an additional or a different method that returns a regular expression string that expresses the combination of the original regex and the flags applied.  Only speculative answers are possible, but I observe that

- `Pattern` also has a `flags()` method, by which the flags can be retrieved.  Using this together with `pattern()`, it is possible to compile a new `Pattern` that is effectively identical to the original, *provided that the pattern does not modify the flags globally* (see comments on the question for more information about this qualification).
- It is conceivable that `Pattern` users would have a use for distinguishing between flags incorporated into the regex string, and those passed separately as flags.

> And if I wanted it, how would I get it other than `"(?i)" + pattern`?

As far as I am aware, there is no built-in mechanism for obtaining a regex string such as you want.  You can, however, build such a mechanism with the help of `Pattern.flags()`.  The basic mode of operation of such a mechanism probably would not be much different from what you present, though.

Comment: `.flags()` returns an int, though, so you suggest bit shifting and masking around `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` and the others just to build a `"(?i)"` string?

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, interpreting the `flags` integer requires using `Pattern`'s flag constants as bitmasks (but no shifting is necessary).  For your purpose, you would use the results to construct the contents of a flag string such as `"(?i)"`.

Answer (score 1):

`Pattern.pattern()` just returns the `pattern` property, unmodified, and
`Pattern.toString()` does the same. You can say it's a shortcoming of the Java 1.5 spec.

But the `(?)` prefix is an *alternative way* of specifying pattern flags.

To really check the flags, use `Pattern.flags()`:

```
    System.out.println(pNoEmbed.pattern() + ", flags=" + pNoEmbed.flags());
    System.out.println(pEmbed.pattern() + ", flags=" + pEmbed.flags());
```

Prints:

```
[ a-z]+, flags=2
(?i)[ a-z]+, flags=2
```

So, you could strip the `(?i)` and just rely on `flags` instead.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer how I could get back `(?i)` if I wanted it. The integer is nice to have, but doesn't mean much without some conditional check against `CASE_INSENSITIVE`

Comment: @cricket_007 - you can't, sorry if that was unclear. You have to check the flags and maybe generate one yourself, but keep in mind that you'll have to merge it with any existing flags.